# AWS data pipeline, run Unload of redshift from bash shell script and save to S3

Tags: bash, shell, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, pipeline

I like to run unload to get data from Redshift to `s3`, can I run it using bash shell script of Data pipeline? if yes, what is the command inside shell script?

Is the following code working in shell script?

```
unload ('select * from ......') 
to 's3://mybucket/venue_pipe_' iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::0123456789012:role/MyRedshiftRole';
```

Comment: please edit this question instead https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56605235/how-to-load-redshift-data-to-s3-from-aws-data-pipeline

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load redshift data to S3 from AWS data pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56605235/how-to-load-redshift-data-to-s3-from-aws-data-pipeline)

Comment: The other question is about load, this one is about unload. I'm not competent to decide whether they are similar enough to be merged as duplicates.

Comment: This one is marginally better than the old one, but begs the question "did you try? what happened?" Neither `unload` nor `to` are valid shell commands in isolation, though of course it's possible that they are available in some environment. Even then the unquoted parentheses are syntactically invalid. So the short and sweet answer is probably "No."

Comment: Thanks. So it means "unload" command can't be recognized in Shell script. this is what i want to know.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it from command line or shell script but you need a client like `psql` (On Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install -y postgresql-client`).

The command looks like:

```
PGPASSWORD='YOURPASS' psql -h your.redshift.end.point.com -U youruser -d yourdb -p 5439 -c "...unload query here..."
```

Comment: I need to run it from AWS pipeline, i thought "unload" is working inside shell. I am new to AWS and redshift.